# Child setting a flag read by parent C

Tags: c, process, fork

After I `fork()` the child will do a number of comparisons involving some function calls and setting some flags.  The parent just goes to the end to wait for the child.  In one case I don't want the parent to wait for the child (running in the background).  I think the problem is that the child takes too long to set the flag and the parent is already at the end.  Following the parent and child processes shows the flag is being set correctly but not being read by the parent correctly.  Is there anyway to stall the parent?

Comment: How do you read from the flag? Changes done to the memory by the child are not visible to the parent and vice-versa.

Comment: FUZxxl is correct. Forking creates a new process with its own memory. You can't set a flag in the child and have it read by the parent unless you allocate shared memory. Perhaps you just want a separate thread not a separate process?

Comment: I did not know that.  How would I allocate shared memory?

Comment: Here's a good and simple guide explaining shared memory segment programming in Unix: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/shm.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wait(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) using the pid of the child to stall the parent until the child has terminated.
As Dipstick said, if it is not necessary to create a new process, a thread would be better. Threads make programs more complicated, but are much more efficient (1000-fold, I guess) than processes due to the fact that there is no task-switching.
Consider: [Pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthreads)

Answer (score 0):

Once you fork a child from the parent, they become different processes with their own address space. So, the changes made by the child on a variable is not visible to the parent.

To have communication between these two processes. You should use any of these [IPC](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html) mechanisms. I do believe the [shared memory](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) approach fits your needs best since the child process gets a snapshot of the parent memory pages.